# How can I pass an array in HTML file?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have an a tag in my HTML file and I have "myfunc" function in my PHP file. How can I pass an array in href to my "myfunc" function?

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo myfunc("this is arg1 witch is string", ['id']); ?>">delete</a>
```

And this is my PHP function:

```
function myfunc($str,$param=[])
{ 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How can there be any array in href?

Comment: @vivek_23 i want pass an string and an array to myfunc method and echo return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have arrays in a `URL` but if you must it should be in `encoded` format, I have written a demo code, see if this resolves your issue↓↓

**View**

```
<?php 
    $id = array('1', '2');

    // convert the array to JSON objects and then convert the string(object) to query part of the URL.
    $id = urlencode(json_encode($id));
?>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url("home/form/this is arg1 witch is string/{$id}"); ?>">delete</a>
```

**Controller**

```
function form($str, $param){

    echo urldecode($str); // convert the URL string back into its original form 
    echo '<br>';
    print_r(json_decode(urldecode($param)));  // Convert the URL string into encoded form and then convert it back to an array.
}
```

> **Output** 
> `this is arg1 which is string` 
> `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )`

Read More about [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter, you can create a function in the controller and then,

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function myfunction($str, $param = []){
         return "something";
    }
}
```

In the respective view

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo $this->myfunc("this is arg1 witch is string", ['id']); ?>">delete</a>
```

But the recomended way is to preprocess the data and pass it to the view , decribed in [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view).